# SQL query for total unique hits

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling to write the correct sql statement to yield the desired result for my normalized tables.

I have:

```
Table: sites
id, url
1, google.com
2, facebook.com

Table: hits
id, site_id
1, 1
2, 1
3, 1
4, 2
```

I'd like to write an sql statement to produce something like the following:

```
site_id, total_hits
1, 3
2, 1
```

This would show the count of how many times each url has been hit. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select s.site_id, count(*) as totalhits
from sites s join hits h
on s.site_id = h.site_id
group by s.site_id
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5809/1

You should do a `group by` on site id and count the number of hits.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a `join`:

```
select h.site_id, count(*) as totalhits
from hits h
group by h.site_id;
```

You would need a join in two situations.  First, if some hits don't have a valid `site_id` (unlikely because `site_id` should be a foreign key to the `sites` table), or if some sites didn't have a hit and you wanted to include them.  If so, use `left join`:

```
select s.site_id, count(h.site_side) as totalhits
from sites s left join
     hits h
     on s.site_id = h.site_id
group by s.site_id;
```